# Ruby install of fastthread-1.0.7 and Sup

Tags: ruby, sup

When trying to install Sup via MacPorts I get :-

```
>--->  Computing dependencies for sup
>--->  Dependencies to be installed: rb-fastthread rb-ferret rb-gettext rb-locale rb-highline rb-lockfile >rb-mime-types rb-ncurses-ruby rb-net-ssh rb-rake rb-rmail rb-trollop
>--->  Verifying checksum(s) for rb-fastthread
>Error: Checksum (md5) mismatch for fastthread-1.0.7.gem
>Error: Checksum (sha1) mismatch for fastthread-1.0.7.gem
>Error: Checksum (rmd160) mismatch for fastthread-1.0.7.gem
>***
>The non-matching file appears to be HTML. See this page for possible reasons
>for the checksum mismatch:
><http://trac.macports.org/wiki/MisbehavingServers>
>***
>Error: Target org.macports.checksum returned: Unable to verify file checksums
>Error: Failed to install rb-fastthread
>Log for rb-fastthread is at: >/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_ruby_rb->fastthread/main.log
>Error: The following dependencies were not installed: rb-fastthread rb-ferret rb-gettext rb-locale rb->highline rb-lockfile rb-mime-types rb-ncurses-ruby rb-net-ssh rb-rake rb-rmail rb-trollop
>Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
>To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

The error seems to indicate that the my DNS servers are not re-directing properly, but I am using Goolge's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 servers, so this shouldn't be an issue.

OSX 10.6 and ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10].

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Tried sudo gem install sup with these results :-

```
>sudo gem install sup
>Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>ERROR:  Error installing sup:
>        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

>/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>checking for unistd.h... yes
>checking for locale.h... yes
>checking for ncurses.h... yes
>checking for wmove() in -lncursesw... no
>checking for wmove() in -lpdcurses... no
>*** extconf.rb failed ***
>Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
>details.  You may need configuration options.

>Provided configuration options:
>        --with-opt-dir
>        --without-opt-dir
>        --with-opt-include
>        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>        --with-opt-lib
>        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>        --with-make-prog
>        --without-make-prog
>        --srcdir=.
>        --curdir
>        --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
>        --with-ncurseswlib
>        --without-ncurseswlib
>        --with-pdcurseslib
>        --without-pdcurseslib
>extconf.rb:46: ncurses library not found (RuntimeError)
```

I had previously installed ncurses via sudo port install ncurses +universial

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Mac OSX comes with ncurses installed already, so it could just be a $PATH issue? Does `locate ncurses` show anything helpful? If I run it here I have some stuff in /Developer (iPhone .dylibs), the ports files, and some stuff in /usr/include and /usr/lib, including:

```
/usr/bin/ncurses5.4-config
/usr/include/ncurses.h
/usr/include/ncurses_dll.h
/usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
/usr/lib/libncurses.5.dylib
/usr/lib/libncurses.dylib
```

You could always try locating the ncurses lib manually and then changing the configuration options for `gem install sup`